# My voicemail number transfers to 000

Tags: calls

My voicemail number #101 when dialled, dials the emergency services #000 how do I stop it happening?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings>call>voicemail. Change the number to the one your carrier requires. Check online to find out what number that would be. I'm not sure if dialing #101 will do the trick, but after changing the above settings, long press on number 1 in the dialing app and that should bring up your voicemail

Comment: No still doing the same 

Comment: What carrier do you have

Comment: Boost which is Telstra

Comment: It seems like it might be an issue with the carrier. All i can suggest is you should contact your carrier.